# Is there an equivalent of Thread.threadDictionary in Swift structured concurrency?

Tags: swift, multithreading

I have a framework that uses `Thread.threadDictionary` to provide shared state that affects how methods behave when executed inside the same thread.

I want to add support for the new Swift structured concurrency, but AFAIK there's no guarantee that code executed through Swift structured concurrency executes in the same `Thread` even if it's all scoped in the same `Task`.

So, how can I share state across `async` methods without explicitly passing in a state object when using Swift structured concurrency? Is there an equivalent to `Thread.threadDictionary` that I don't know about?

Comment: Try to forget that you've ever heard about threads. If you want to guarantee thread-sameness, use an Actor.

Comment: See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0311-task-locals.md

Comment: I'm not sure an actor would ensure thread-sameness - individual mutations to the actor could run on different threads, their access to the actor would just be synchronized.

Comment: @matt Right, but I was looking for a Task state solution (basically what Alexander posted). I don't really care about thread-sameness.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. Can you post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for task-local storage, which is accessed via [`TaskLocal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/tasklocal)

Comment: Here an introductory article on detached Task and TaskLocal values: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/whats-the-difference-between-a-task-and-a-detached-task , a more abstracted "Thread-local storage" in Swift.